# Pip error -> ImportError: No module named helpers

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip, helper

When I'm trying to install any package using pip it gives an error. It shows `"ImportError: No module named helpers"`. I tried installing the helpers module using pip but the same error occurred. I'm pasting the output of the error message. Operating System: Arch Linux.

```
pip2 install requests
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip2", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==18.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2793, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2411, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2417, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.ui import BAR_TYPES
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/ui.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.progress.helpers import HIDE_CURSOR, SHOW_CURSOR, WritelnMixin
ImportError: No module named helpers
```

Comment: Looks like a dependence (helpers) is misssing: `pip install helpers`. Then `pip install requests`.

Comment: Same error shows up for "pip install helpers".

pip2 install helpers
Traceback (most recent call last):

ImportError: No module named helpers

Comment: What if you run `sudo apt install python-pip --upgrade` ?

Comment: The error still persists. I tried to upgrade pip but it's updated. I think the pip itself is not working, maybe there is some kind of bugs in the package itself. I still really don't understand what is  'helpers'.

Comment: `sudo apt purge python-pip && sudo apt install python-pip`

Comment: I'm not using Debian based operating system. I am using Arch Linux. But I have removed pip and reinstalled it and the error remains.
[pacman -Rsc python2-pip &&
pacman -S python2-pip]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help. I found out the solution. When I upgraded to python 3.7 pip was broken. 
Executing these commands solved the issue.

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages
python3.7 -m ensurepip
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Same can be used with Python2 as well, just replacing 3.7 with 2.7 and pip with pip2.