# (Python) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.progress'

Tags: python

When I try to install the latest discord.py version, I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\44794\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\44794\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\44794\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Users\44794\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\44794\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\44794\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\44794\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "C:\Users\44794\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.progress.bar import Bar, FillingCirclesBar, IncrementalBar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.progress'
```

I am new to python and stuff like that, so please don't go all technical. Pretend you're speaking to, like, a four-year-old. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be that the pip is broken - try to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55069451/pip-error-importerror-no-module-named-helpers

Comment: @DawidGacek thanks for the response. `py -3 -m ensurepip` worked fine, but `pip install --upgrade pip` returned an error saying: `Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\44794\aanaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\44794\aanaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py install --upgrade pip'`